# MS Access - Group By and Sum if all values are available query

Tags: ms-access, sum

I am trying to create a query in ms access which sums up costs but want to exclude those that have no value from the result. I am struggling because I want to exclude items from one column based on another column.

I have a column with finished product, column with components that make up finished product, column with quantity of components required for finished product and column with cost for each of components. What I need is to get total cost for each component required and then sum up costs as total cost for finished product which is simple enough.

However there are some blank fields where cost for one or more components are not available, I want those to show in the result with text " Pending " for finished product instead of it summing up only available values.

Below example of what I am trying to do:

[BOM_List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtNGs.png)

What I need in result is below:

[BOM_Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5SdY.png)

Would really appreciate any help on this :)

Comment: Build query that calculates sums. Use that query as source for a query that calculates with an IIf() expression to return number as string or "Pending". Or use sum query as RecordSource to build a report and do calc in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on June 7ths comment and assuming Table2:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         ID         |       FinishedProductid        |     ItemNumber     |     Component      |        Uom         |      ComponentQuantity       |      ComponentUnit       |      stdCost       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |                      199127402 |                 10 |          123123123 | PC                 |                            3 | PC                       |              $1.50 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |                      199127402 |                 20 |          321321321 | PC                 |                            1 | PC                       |              $2.50 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 |                      199127402 |                 30 |          123456789 | PC                 |                            1 | PC                       |              $3.55 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 |                      199127402 |                 40 |          987654321 | PC                 |                         0.25 | H                        |             $82.00 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 |                      199127403 |                 10 |          111222333 | PC                 |                            3 | PC                       |              $1.50 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  6 |                      199127403 |                 20 |          333222111 | PC                 |                            1 | PC                       |                    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  7 |                      199127403 |                 30 |          444555666 | PC                 |                            1 | PC                       |              $3.55 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  8 |                      199127403 |                 40 |          666555444 | PC                 |                         0.25 | H                        |             $82.00 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: Total query]

```
'resulting sql to get all FinishedProductids


SELECT Table2.FinishedProductid
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.FinishedProductid;
```

[image: query to calculate total cost]

```
'once have FinishedProductid's out of the group statement you can just use a calculated variable

SELECT Query2.FinishedProductid, getTotalCost([FinishedProductid]) AS TotalCost
FROM Query2;
```

```
'of course a getTotalCost function is needed.  Add the following to a code module

Public Function getTotalCost(FinishedProductid As Long) As String
If isPending(FinishedProductid) Then
getTotalCost = "Pending"
Else
getTotalCost = DSum("ComponentQuantity*stdCost", "Table2", "FinishedProductid = " & FinishedProductid)
End If
End Function


Public Function isPending(FinishedProductid) As Boolean
' if any values of stdCost are null set isPending to true
'public functions can be accessed most anywhere in Access

Dim nullCount As Long
nullCount = DCount("ID", "Table2", "FinishedProductid = " & FinishedProductid & " AND ISNULL(stdCost)")
If nullCount > 0 Then
isPending = True
Else
isPending = False
End If
End Function
```

```
'result

-------------------------------------------------------
|       FinishedProductid        |     TotalCost      |
-------------------------------------------------------
|                      199127402 | 31.05              |
-------------------------------------------------------
|                      199127403 | Pending            |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Explanation: I use a two query approach to get around the sql complications that arise from the group by.  The functions are relatively declaritive and hence self-commenting.  Finally, functions can be reused.

Edit: getTotalCost returns a string so it can meet the requirement of returning both the string "pending" and the total cost

Comment: I am fairly new to access and I am not sure where public function code is to be added. Is this supposed to be a seperate query?

Comment: in Access 2016 specifically, there is a create tab on the ribbon.  on the far right of that tab click module (don't click class module as that is for adding classes).  This adds a module to your database.  Modules are similar to the form code behind sections where you write code for form events.  However, form code behind is scoped to only be visible to said form.  public functions in modules are viewable most anywhere in the database.  For instance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haCfJTnrTYs