# Only show matching values from junction table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have tables *service* and *material* and *service_material*.

The table service cointains warranty_dates that stores multiple values for all materials used on the service. The warranty length is in table material, and the warranty_dates in table service is calculated with service_date plus warranty lengths from table materials.

I'm trying to create a query in Access that will show me only the warranty dates for materials used on a service, so only the values that match the serviceid in service_material table.

> Servis = Service, Datum = date, Garancija = warranty, Ime = name

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Servis.Datum+Material.Garancija AS garancijski_rok, Servis.Datum, Material.Ime, Servis_Material.ServisID
FROM Servis 
INNER JOIN (Material 
INNER JOIN Servis_Material ON Material.MaterialID = Servis_Material.MaterialID) ON Servis.ServisID = Servis_Material.ServisID
WHERE (((Servis_Material.ServisID)=[Servis].[ServisID]) AND ((Servis_Material.materialid)=[material].[materialid]))
ORDER BY Servis_Material.ServisID;
```

This is what I have so far, but this query shows me all warranty dates for all materials used in services. I just want the query to show the matching materials that were used in service.

I'm a total beginner and I'm using Excel because it's a school project. Sorry cause it's in Slovenian. Hopefully it is still understandable.

This is the result atm. If it's possible I want it to only show materials for that particular service I am adding the warranty dates in.

Comment: I'm confused by the language and apparent normalization problems.  I suggest making a new database with just the 3 tables and some sample data and add a table showing what you want.  You can export tables to text from access.

Comment: Why do you have a WHERE clause that essentially replicates the ON clauses? I am also confused by your statement of requirement - INNER JOIN to junction table should produce desired dataset. Clarify "particular service I am adding the warranty dates in" - do you need to apply a filter that references a value on a form?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with access and not Excel and assuming the problem is mostly setting up the ManytoMany Relationship.  Here is a Minimal Reproducible example starting with the Normalized Tables:

[image]

```
-------------------------------------------
|     ServiceID      |    ServiceDate     |
-------------------------------------------
|                  1 |         12/12/2022 |
-------------------------------------------
|                  2 |          12/5/2022 |
-------------------------------------------
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|     MaterialID     |    MaterialName    |   WarantyLength    |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | PartA              |                 10 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | PartB              |                200 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 | PartC              |                300 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| MaterialServiceID  |     MaterialID     |     ServiceID      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |                  1 |                  1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |                  2 |                  1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 |                  3 |                  1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 |                  1 |                  2 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 |                  2 |                  2 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Regarding Table Normalization, note how ServiceDate is the only thing hanging on Services and What would be more clearly named as MaterialWarantyLength is hanging on Materials.  What would best be called LastDayofMaterialWaranty would be under MaterialsServices but we have a formula so we calculate that as needed.

One way of thinking about the next step is: Database users interact with the database through forms and reports.  Among other things this protects the database from Users entering bad data and Protects the User from having to understand those normalized tables.

aside: the default forms are not good at protecting the database from bad data but they are a jump start.

So, the next step will be a query that puts the data for this relationship back together into one big table that the Database designer can understand.  I find myself adjusting for the user when I design the User interface of forms and reports.  Here I put everything into the designers query which is a good default as what you don't need for a particular form you just don't show.

[image]

```
'Warranty is a calculated Field.  
'Note the use of DateAdd to handle all those calendar problems

'normally I extract the code for calculated fields into public functions for an example of that see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74621501/ms-access-group-by-and-sum-if-all-values-are-available-query/74673498#74673498

Warranty: DateAdd("d",[Materials].[WarantyLength],[Services].[ServiceDate])
```

```
'here is the resulting sql for the designer query
'if you are following along try pasting the sql into the sql pane and then going to differnt tabs of the query designer

SELECT Services.ServiceID, Services.ServiceDate, MaterialsServices.MaterialID, Materials.WarantyLength, Materials.MaterialName
FROM Services INNER JOIN (Materials INNER JOIN MaterialsServices ON Materials.MaterialID = MaterialsServices.MaterialID) ON Services.ServiceID = MaterialsServices.ServiceID;
```

Running the query on the sample data gives:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     ServiceID      |    ServiceDate     |     MaterialID     |        WarantyLength        |    MaterialName    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |         12/12/2022 |                  1 |                          10 | PartA              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |         12/12/2022 |                  2 |                         200 | PartB              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |         12/12/2022 |                  3 |                         300 | PartC              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |          12/5/2022 |                  1 |                          10 | PartA              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |          12/5/2022 |                  2 |                         200 | PartB              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

At this point it is down to how you want the user to interact with the data. For instance, for a jump start I selected the query and used the create-form wizard to get a tabular style form and then added an unbound combobox to the header to allow the end user to filter the resulting form.

See here for an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq3cgaHF6fc

The Final Form allows the end user to switch between viewing different services :

[image]

[image]

```
Private Sub cmbService_AfterUpdate()
Me.Filter = "ServiceID = " & Me.cmdService
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```